# How to Delete Browser Local stroage data after 1 day?

Tags: javascript

I'm Trying to delete browser Local storage data after 1 day.

i have tried below code.

```
function cleanupExpiredMessages() {
        const messages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chatMessages')) || [];
        const now = new Date().getTime();
        const expirationTime = 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
    
        const validMessages = messages.filter(messageObj => now - messageObj.timestamp <= expirationTime);
    
        localStorage.removeItem('chatMessages', JSON.stringify(validMessages));
        
    }
    
    setInterval(cleanupExpiredMessages, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

when save on browser message is like below.

```
{"sender":"user","message":"hi\n","timestamp":1693571163881},{"sender":"bot","message":"Hello! How can I assist you today?","timestamp":1693571169378}
```

Need expert Help.

Thanks

Comment: What is not working? Do you expect the page to be loaded full 24 hours without refresh?

Comment: Are you trying to update the messages? You appear to blanket remove everything instead of updating when you do: `localStorage.removeItem('chatMessages', JSON.stringify(validMessages));` (`remove` only takes one parameter, the key, was that meant to be a `set`?)

Comment: The `removeItem()` only accepts a single parameter which is the `ItemKey`. Why do you pass `JSON.stringify(validMessages)` as the second parameter? You probably want to remove expired messages from your JSON, then overwrite the value with `setItem()`

Comment: seconding @Konrad's point - `setInterval()` with 24 hours will only work if the user remains on this web page for 24+ hours (and maybe not even then due to browser background processes). If they close the tab/window and come back after > 24 hours, this function won't run on page load. It looks like you're keeping track of the message timestamp, so you just need to adjust your `cleanupExpiredMessages` function to delete any old messages on page load, and then maybe every minute after that in case the user is doing other things on your site and the message expires while they're doing so.

Comment: Hi, i want remove all chat after 24H from browser storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost right. **but** 2 things:

1. You are using `removeItem` wrong. It only takes 1 argument which is the key of the item and removes it. The second argument is useless here.
2. You **don't need to** remove then set item, You can simply **overwrite** the item with valid messages.

```
const validMessages = messages.filter(
      messageObj => (now - messageObj.timestamp) <= expirationTime );
    
localStorage.setItem('chatMessages', JSON.stringify(validMessages));
```

Comment: I have use before like this - localStorage.setItem('chatMessages', JSON.stringify(validMessages)); But the thing is it was not replacing with new chat message. it just adding. one by one.

Comment: I need after one day user see empty chat box.